# Возможно ли использовать COM-объекты в приложениях android?

Tags: android, com

уважаемые.
Прошу подсказать, можно ли использовать COM-объекты в приложениях андроид?
Если да, то каким образом - укажите, пожалуйста, направление, что почитать, куда копать?
Спасибо.

Comment: COM-объекты из Windows использовать в Linux?

Comment: нельзя, но можно прикрутить dll или даже сборки .net в xamarin-либы и использовать их в приложении.